# Why thread in background is not waiting for task to complete?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am playing with async await feature of C#. Things work as expected when I use it with UI thread. But when I use it in a non-UI thread it doesn't work as expected. Consider the code below

```
private void Click_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += BgDoWork;
        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += BgOnRunWorkerCompleted;
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void BgOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs runWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    {
    }

    private async void BgDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        await Method();
    }


    private static async Task Method()
    {
        for (int i = int.MinValue; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            var http = new HttpClient();
            var tsk = await http.GetAsync("http://www.ebay.com");
        }
    }
```

When I execute this code, background thread don't wait for long running task in `Method` to complete. Instead it instantly executes the `BgOnRunWorkerCompleted` after calling `Method`. Why is that so? What am I missing here?

P.S: I am not interested in alternate ways or correct ways of doing this. I want to know what is actually happening behind the scene in this case? Why is it not waiting?

Comment: You may find my [async/await intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, `BgDoWork` is called on a background thread by the `BackgroundWorker`

It calls `Method`, which starts the loop and calls `http.GetAsync`

`GetAsync` returns a `Task` and continues it's work on another thread.

You `await` the Task which, because the `Task` has not completed, returns from `Method`

Similarly, the await in `BgDoWork` returns another `Task`

So, the `BackgroundWorker` sees that `BgDoWork` has returned and assumes it has completed.

It then raises `RunWorkerCompleted`

---

Basically, don't mix `BackgroundWorker` with `async / await`!

Comment: so only way to achieve this would be to call wait in background thread to make sure it waits for the long running task to end?

Comment: I can't explain `async / await` in an answer or comment - it's too complex. There are lots of tutorials on the web - [here's one on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: It's not a matter of how BackgroundWorker works. According to the docs, you can't execute async event handlers synchronously because they can't return a Task

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there are two problems with your code:

1. `BackgroundWorker` wasn't updated to work with `async`. And the whole point of `async` methods is that they actually return the first time they `await` something that's not finished yet, instead of blocking. So, when your method returns (after an `await`), `BackgroundWorker` thinks it's completed and raises `RunWorkerCompleted`.
2. `BgDoWork()` is an `async void` method. Such methods are “fire and forget”, you can't wait for them to complete. So, if you run your method with something that understands `async`, you would also need to change it to `async Task` method.

You said you aren't looking for alternatives, but I think it might help you understand the problem if I provided one. Assuming that `BgDoWork()` should run on a background thread and `BgOnRunWorkerCompleted()` should run back on the UI thread, you can use code like this:

```
private async void Click_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run((Func<Task>)BgDoWork);
    BgOnRunWorkerCompleted();
}

private void BgOnRunWorkerCompleted()
{
}

private async Task BgDoWork()
{
    await Method();
}
```

Here, `Task.Run()` works as an `async`-aware alternative to `BackgroundWorker` (it runs the method on a background thread and returns a `Task` that can be used to wait until it actually completes). After `await` in `Click_Button()`, you're back on the UI thread, so that's where `BgOnRunWorkerCompleted()` will run. `Click_Button()` is an `async void` method and this is pretty much the only situation where you would want to use one: in an event handler method, that you don't need to wait on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some reason for the background thread to stay alive while it's waiting for `Method()` to complete.  Having an outstanding continuation is not enough to keep a thread alive, so your background worker terminates before `Method()` completes.

You can prove this to yourself by changing your code so that the background thread does a `Thread.Sleep` after the `await Method()`.  That's almost certainly not the real behaviour you want, but if the thread sleeps for long enough you'll see `Method()` complete.

Answer (score 1):

Following is how [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) is raised and handled. (code retrieved using [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com) tool).

```
private void WorkerThreadStart(object argument)
{
    object result = null;
    Exception error = null;
    bool cancelled = false;
    try
    {
        DoWorkEventArgs e = new DoWorkEventArgs(argument);
        this.OnDoWork(e);
        if (e.Cancel)
        {
            cancelled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = e.Result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception2)
    {
        error = exception2;
    }
    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs arg = new RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs(result, error, cancelled);
    this.asyncOperation.PostOperationCompleted(this.operationCompleted, arg);
}


protected virtual void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DoWorkEventHandler handler = (DoWorkEventHandler) base.Events[doWorkKey];
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

There is no special handling to wait for async method. (using async/await keyword).

To make it wait for async operation, following changes are required.

```
async private void WorkerThreadStart(object argument)

    await this.OnDoWork(e);


async protected virtual void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)

    await handler(this, e);
```

But then, [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is .net 2.0 construct, and [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) are .net 4.5. it will be full circle, if any one of these uses other construct.

Comment: I'm not sure why are you bringing decompiled source of `BackgroundWorker` into this. `DbDoWork()` is `async void` method, and you can't wait on that, no matter what.

Comment: Intention was to show, async/await complete chaining is required in order to wait. If any one link does not wait in the chain, calling method does not wait for async method to finish. I have faced this issue sometimes, these are generally encountered at runtime. Usually Visual Studio shows warnings in those cases. Regarding async void, we can still wait by getting the underlying task, and then waiting on the task.

Comment: And how exactly would you get that “underlying Task”, when all you have is a `void` returning method?

Answer (score 1):

You can't await an event handler because it doesn't return anything to await on. From the documentation of the [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) keyword:

> The void return type is used primarily to define event handlers, where a void return type is required. The caller of a void-returning async method can't await it and can't catch exceptions that the method throws.

By adding the async keyword to the BgDoWork event handler you are instructing .NET to execute the handler asynchronously and return as soon as the first yielding operation is encountered. In this case, this happens after the first call to http.GetAsync